# Buy host and domain - a few noob questions

Tags: hosting

1. On the buy host, I need to complete this values. What I suppose to put there?

http://www.softsyshosting.com/Windows-VPS-HyperV.aspx

- Hostname: ?
- NS1 Prefix: ?
- NS2 Prefix: ?

  I don't have my domain yet, and I will buy it in a different location. (GoDaddy).

  2. GoDaddy asking me if I want their email service. My question is from who I need to buy the email (admin@site-name.com) service? not from the hoster?

Comment: "buy host" where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The original question isn't very clear.  I'm not sure what you mean by "buy host" in this context.  If you're purchasing web hosting, usually they will ask what your domain name is and then provide you with two or more name servers which you would use in your DNS delegations at the registrar.  From there, the hosting company would provide your web and e-mail hosting, or whatever you've purchased from them.
2. Your choice of e-mail provider isn't necessarily linked to your domain registrar.  You could purchase the domain name from GoDaddy, have your DNS service with an outside DNS hosting company, and have your web and e-mail hosting with yet another hosting provider.  GoDaddy, however, can provide all of those services under one roof if you want to use their services.

Comment: What is the DNS registration? Cna you look on this link http://www.softsyshosting.com/Windows-VPS-HyperV.aspx,  the $39/month plan? press `order now` and you'll see this section: Configure Server.

Comment: Their form isn't very clear about what they are looking for.  I'd recommend calling them and asking their sales department directly.  They may be assuming that you're purchasing a new domain through them as part of the package.  If they don't have phone support, I'd recommend looking for another provider.